# How to solve error related to name repair startegy with double pivot_longer

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pivot, data-cleaning

I have been trying to convert separately columns as long format, by using the following code:

```
mtcars %>% 
  pivot_longer(1:3, values_to = 'values') %>% 
  pivot_longer(6:7, values_to = 'values1')
```

However, I am getting the following error

```
**Error in `pivot_longer()`:
! Names must be unique.
x These names are duplicated:
  * "name" at locations 7 and 9.
i Use argument `names_repair` to specify repair strategy.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.**
```

can anyone know how to avoid this error and how to separately convert different chunks of columns as long format, possibly in the same `pivot_longer` call?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that possible to embody in a single operation (I mean in the same pivot_longer() function) these two separated operations? How will be that possible?

Comment: I don't know if I follow 12666727b9. Check my answer though for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be seen by looking at the documentation, and looking at the first part of your code.

#### The documentation

These are the arguments for `pivot_longer()`, along with their default arguments, if any:

```
pivot_longer(
  data,
  cols,
  ...,
  cols_vary = "fastest",
  names_to = "name", <--- important part
  names_prefix = NULL,
  names_sep = NULL,
  names_pattern = NULL,
  names_ptypes = NULL,
  names_transform = NULL,
  names_repair = "check_unique",
  values_to = "value",
  values_drop_na = FALSE,
  values_ptypes = NULL,
  values_transform = NULL
)
```

As you can see, if you don't give a name for the name column (with the `names_to` argument), it defaults to the name "name".

#### Your code

Running `mtcars %>% pivot_longer(1:3, values_to = 'values')`, we get the output:

```
# A tibble: 96 × 10
      hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb name  values
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
 1   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 mpg     21  
 2   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 cyl      6  
 3   110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 disp   160  
 4   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 mpg     21  
 5   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 cyl      6  
 6   110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 disp   160  
 7    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 mpg     22.8
 8    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 cyl      4  
 9    93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 disp   108  
10   110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 mpg     21.4
# ℹ 86 more rows
```

Notice the 'name' column on the end? When we try to run `pivot_longer(6:7, values_to = 'values1')` after this, we're trying to create a 'name' column again, but we already have one, so dplyr freaks out and throws this error.

There's a few things we can do:

1. assign names to the name columns (e.g. use `names_to = "name1"` for the first one, and `names_to = "name2"` for the second)
2. add an option to names_repair: to quote the documentation -

> The default, "check_unique" is to error if the columns are duplicated. Use "minimal" to allow duplicates in the output, or "unique" to de-duplicated by adding numeric suffixes. See vctrs::vec_as_names() for more options.

3. use `names_to = NULL` to drop the names column

Comment: Well my question was if it is possible to write down something like `mtcars %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(1:3, 6:7), names_to = c('name1', 'name2'), 
               values_to = c('values_1', 'values_2'), names_sep = '_')`? This gives some error to me

Comment: hmmm that's not how I read your question! You said *possibly*

Comment: Yes, it was a furrther curiosity aside my main question

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible, at least with pivot_longer(). In the case of the code you gave , c(1:3, 6:7) is equivalent to c(1:7) (try running `c(1:3, 6:7) == c(1,2,3, 6, 7)` and seeing what you get)

Comment: if everything was encoded in the column names, you could do it in one go, using the column names and the names_sep argument. That's for parsing things where (for example) there might be many columns with names like "ford_red" "ford_blue", "toyota_red", and you just want a company and colour column